# Mini PC USB ports acting out after hot plug in

Tags: hard-drive, usb, desktop-computer, usb-storage, openmediavault

I have a MeLE Mini PC Quieter3Q in which I installed OpenMediaVault to use as file/media server. I also plug a USB fan which I place on top of this mini PC for added cooling:

[image: MeLE Quieter3Q with USB fan]

Everything was awesome with this setup until I plugged in a 3.5 HDD and I didn't realize the power switch of the enclosure was on.

OpenMediaVault started freezing and to test the mini PC I installed Debian 11 with no problems. I connected USB drives and they work fine. Then, I plugged in the USB fan and all hell broke loose. I had to unplug the mini PC power cord to turn it off (the power button became unresponsive). After turning on the mini PC again without the usb fan everything is back to normal.

I wonder if there is something in the BIOS that could reset the USB ports and being able to use the fan again.

Comment: Using a USB powered fan seems questionable -- the fan itself requires power, causing the PC to run a bit hotter. Why not use a mains powered fan?

Comment: ... or any 5V phone charger instead of connecting it to the PC's USB ports.